# Show div based on if text string equals a specific string

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking through all kinds of information to figure out how to do this. What I am looking for is to show a div based on what is entered in a text box within a form. Later I plan on incorporating this into a form we are currently using in Joomla. This is what I have tried, among other things. This is the most basic attempt. Essentially I want this code example to spit out text value depending on what is entered. In this case, if "yes" is entered, it will spit out "Success", and if anything else is entered, it will spit out "No Luck". From there I would like it to actually show a div. But that's for later, I suppose unless anyone knows how to get there from here. With this code, only "No Luck" gets outputted, regardless if you input "Yes". Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to contribute!

```
<head>
  <script>
      function show()
      {
      var input = document.getElementById("someInput");
      if(input == "yes"){
        document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "Success";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "No Luck";}
      }
  </script>
</head>

<html>
  <input id="someInput" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="show()">
  <br><br>
    <div id="someDiv">

  </div>

  <br>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.value` property if it's an input element

```
if(input.value == "yes"){
```

or the `.text` property if you just want the text inside another element

or the `.innerHTML` property if you just want the html inside another element

Comment: I am not sure what `localeCompare` is tbh. Someone edited my answer with that. But give it a shot, otherwise remove it.

Comment: Thank you @ogc-nick for your response. Your snippet nearly worked. All I did to edit was the following:                     

   if(input.value == "yes"){                           

But your answer saved me a lot of headaches. Thank you very much for your help. I am brand new to Stack Exchange, as you can probably see. But I will definitely keep up my presence here and will definitely throw my 2 cents in when it can help others!

Comment: Now all I have to do is figure out how to take this code and transform it so that I can show an entire div based on the text response. I will work on this obviously first before I post for any additional help. Thanks again all! What a great community! And I'll have to check up on other forums on how to give rep points as well as how to format these replies for code. That snippet I just posted looks pretty ugly :(.

Answer (score 0):

Head always belongs inside html tags fyi. Javascript either belongs in the head or the  tag should be the last thing rendered as it is functionally faster to load.

But a solution that appends the success or value to the screen inside the someDiv element should be similar to the following.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputtxt = document.getElementById('someInput');
  var appendLocation = document.getElementById('someDiv');

  function show() {
    if(inputtxt.value === "yes") {
       appendLocation.innerHTML =  appendLocation.innerHTML + "<div>Success</div>";
    }
    else
    {
       appendLocation.innerHTML = appendLocation.innerHTML + "<div>No Luck!</div>";
    }

}
  </script>
 </head>
  <input id="someInput" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="show()">
  <br><br>
    <div id="someDiv">

  </div>

  <br>    
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for you note about the tag placement. I corrected it right away!